# MySQL - Querying for names for a different table corresponding to their ids

Tags: mysql, syntax

I need to get names of from and to users to display messages.

I have two tables
one user table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERS(
 USER_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 USER_EMAILID VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET 'latin1' COLLATE 'latin1_bin' NOT NULL, 
 USER_FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL, 
 USER_LAST_NAME VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID),
 INDEX idx_USER_CONFIG_id2 (USER_EMAILID ASC)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

and Email table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EMAIL (
  MAIL_ID TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
  FROM_ADD INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  TO_ADD INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  EMAIL_SUBJECT VARCHAR(75) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' DEFAULT NULL,
  MESSAGE TEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' DEFAULT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (MAIL_NO)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I need to query for emails for a particular user and below is what I have
[image]
while doing so I also need to bring their names as well. How can I achieve this?

EDIT: (query provided by OP in comment)

```
SELECT B.TO_ADD, B.FROM_ADD, A.USER_FIRST_NAME, B.MESSAGE
FROM EMAIL B LEFT JOIN
     USERS A
     ON (A.USER_ID = B.FROM_ADD OR A.USER_ID = B.TO_ADD)
ORDER BY A.USER_FIRST_NAME DESC;
```

Comment: SELECT  B.TO_ADD, B.FROM_ADD, A.USER_FIRST_NAME,  B.MESSAGE FROM EMAIL B
 LEFT JOIN USERS A ON 
 (A.USER_ID = B.FROM_ADD OR A.USER_ID = B.TO_ADD) ORDER BY A.USER_FIRST_NAME DESC;

Comment: Above is what I have reached so far but its not what I intend to achieve as they come in two row and not one..!!!

Comment: If I didn't missunderstood you, what you need it's to get the name of the first table (users) and the message text of the second one (emails) to show both of them, right?

Comment: yes, I need message and name of people (sender and receiver) in one row

Comment: But in your screenshot it appears all the information in the same row. I think I'm missunderstanding you, sorry :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want two `left join`s:

```
SELECT e.TO_ADD, e.FROM_ADD, ufrom.USER_FIRST_NAME, uto.USER_FIRST_NAME, e.MESSAGE
FROM EMAIL e LEFT JOIN
     USERS ufrom
     ON ufrom.USER_ID = e.FROM_ADD LEFT JOIN
     USERS uto
     ON uto.USER_ID = e.TO_ADD
ORDER BY ufrom.USER_FIRST_NAME DESC;
```

Comment: Wonderful. (Looking into the solution, I can say I would have never got this) This works like charm... Thanks for your fast response.

Comment: Afterthought, I am hoping the scenario did not complicate itself. I am hoping having to use joins is not going to impact the performance. Or is there a better way of handling the email table design?

Comment: Your design is fine.  You don't need to worry about the joins.  You just need indexes on the tables, in this case, `users(user_id)`.

Comment: If I have to put a filter say where e.TO_ADD = '?' how do i refactor this. This is to fetch mails that was send to a given user

Comment: @user4826347 . . . By adding a condition clause . . . `WHERE e.to_Add = <foobar>` or adding it to the appropriate `ON` clause.  It depends what you really want to do.

Comment: I hit a block as the ORDER_BY stopped working when I added GROUP BY. SELECT e.TO_ADD, e.FROM_ADD, ufrom.USER_FIRST_NAME,ufrom.USER_LAST_NAME, uto.USER_FIRST_NAME,uto.USER_LAST_NAME,e.EMAIL_SUBJECT, e.MESSAGE,e.UPDATED_DATE
FROM EMAIL e LEFT JOIN
     USERS ufrom
     ON ufrom.USER_ID = e.FROM_ADD LEFT JOIN
     USERS uto
     ON uto.USER_ID = e.TO_ADD
     GROUP BY e.EMAIL_SUBJECT
ORDER BY e.UPDATED_DATE DESC, uto.USER_LAST_NAME ASC; Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @user4826347 . . . This question does not have an `ORDER BY` in it.  You can try `ORDER BY max(e.Update_date)`.  If that doesn't work, ask another question.

Comment: Thanks. That worked and I had another question on top for which I asked another question  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30830700/mysql-querying-for-unread-messages-along-with-mail-messages