# MySQL - Querying for unread messages along with mail messages

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am in need to retrieve the messages in one query with name of users and in addition count of unread messages. The query being used is the one below and the name of user is retrieved and what is remaining to get count of unread messages. How can I get the unread messages from EMAIL_MESSAGE (MESSAGE_STATUS='U') to this query so that I have the information alongside with other details.

```
SELECT e.MAIL_NO, e.BIZ_ID, e.FROM_ADD, e.TO_ADD, e.EMAIL_SUBJECT,  
      DATE_FORMAT(e.UPDATED_DATE,'%d %b %y, %I:%i %p') AS DATE, e.MAIL_STATUS, 
      CONCAT(ufrom.USER_FIRST_NAME,' ',ufrom.USER_LAST_NAME) AS U_NAME FROM EMAIL e  
LEFT JOIN USER_CONFIG ufrom
     ON ufrom.USER_ID = e.FROM_ADD 
LEFT JOIN USER_CONFIG uto
     ON uto.USER_ID = e.TO_ADD
WHERE 
     e.FROM_ADD=: e.FROM_ADD  
ORDER BY MAX(e.UPDATED_DATE) DESC, ufrom.USER_FIRST_NAME DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USER_CONFIG(
  USER_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  USER_FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL, 
  USER_LAST_NAME VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID),
  INDEX idx_USER_CONFIG_id1 (USER_ID ASC)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EMAIL (
 MAIL_NO INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
 BIZ_ID VARCHAR(35) CHARACTER SET 'latin1' COLLATE 'latin1_bin' NOT NULL, 
 FROM_ADD INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  -- FOR EMAIL_TYPE EUCP, THIS WILL BE AGENT ID
 TO_ADD INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL, -- FOR EMAIL_TYPE EUCP, THIS WILL BE CANDIDATE_ID
 EMAIL_SUBJECT VARCHAR(75) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' DEFAULT NULL, 
 MAIL_STATUS CHAR(1) CHARACTER SET 'latin1' COLLATE 'latin1_bin' DEFAULT 'A', 
 UPDATED_DATE DATETIME ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (MAIL_NO,BIZ_ID),
 INDEX idx_EMAIL_id1 (FROM_ADD ASC),
 INDEX idx_EMAIL_id2 (TO_ADD ASC),
 INDEX idx_EMAIL_id3 (BIZ_ID ASC),
 INDEX idx_EMAIL_id4 (MAIL_STATUS ASC),
 INDEX idx_EMAIL_id5 (EMAIL_SUBJECT ASC), 
 INDEX idx_EMAIL_id6 (UPDATED_DATE ASC)  
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EMAIL_MESSAGE (
  MESSAGE_NO INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
  BIZ_ID VARCHAR(35) CHARACTER SET 'latin1' COLLATE 'latin1_bin' NOT NULL, 
  SENDER INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL, 
  MESSAGE TEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' DEFAULT NULL, 
  ATTACHMENT VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'latin1' COLLATE 'latin1_bin' DEFAULT NULL, 
  MESSAGE_STATUS CHAR(1) CHARACTER SET 'latin1' COLLATE 'latin1_bin' DEFAULT 'U', 
  READ_DATE DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, 
  SEND_DATE DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  PRIMARY KEY (MESSAGE_NO,BIZ_ID),
  INDEX idx_EMAIL_MESSAGE_id1 (SENDER ASC),
  INDEX idx_EMAIL_MESSAGE_id2 (MESSAGE_STATUS ASC)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

If I were have to query the table on its own, I would use

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS UNREAD_MESSAGE_COUNT FROM EMAIL_MESSAGE 
  WHERE BIZ_ID= :BIZID AND MESSAGE_STATUS = 'U';
```

But I am struggling to incorporate to the combined query as given above. Could you help me on this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Lasted email recieved and count of unread (recieved).

```
  SELECT e.MAIL_NO, e.BIZ_ID, e.FROM_ADD, e.TO_ADD, e.EMAIL_SUBJECT,  
  DATE_FORMAT(e.UPDATED_DATE,'%d %b %y, %I:%i %p') AS DATE, e.MAIL_STATUS, 
  CONCAT(ufrom.USER_FIRST_NAME,' ',ufrom.USER_LAST_NAME) AS U_NAME,if(UNREAD_MESSAGE_COUNT is null,0,UNREAD_MESSAGE_COUNT) FROM EMAIL e  
LEFT JOIN USER_CONFIG ufrom
 ON ufrom.USER_ID = e.TO_ADD
left join (SELECT COUNT(*) AS UNREAD_MESSAGE_COUNT,TO_ADD FROM EMAIL_MESSAGE         inner join EMAIL using (BIZ_ID)
WHERE MESSAGE_STATUS = 'U' group by TO_ADD) t on t.TO_ADD= e.TO_ADD
WHERE 
 e.TO_ADD=:TO_ADD
ORDER BY MAX(e.UPDATED_DATE) DESC, ufrom.USER_FIRST_NAME DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Emails sent and count of unread sent messages:

```
  SELECT e.MAIL_NO, e.BIZ_ID, e.FROM_ADD, e.TO_ADD, e.EMAIL_SUBJECT,  
  DATE_FORMAT(e.UPDATED_DATE,'%d %b %y, %I:%i %p') AS DATE, e.MAIL_STATUS, 
  CONCAT(ufrom.USER_FIRST_NAME,' ',ufrom.USER_LAST_NAME) AS U_NAME,if(UNREAD_MESSAGE_COUNT is null,0,UNREAD_MESSAGE_COUNT) FROM EMAIL e  
LEFT JOIN USER_CONFIG ufrom
 ON ufrom.USER_ID = e.FROM_ADD 
left join (SELECT COUNT(*) AS UNREAD_MESSAGE_COUNT,FROM_ADD FROM EMAIL_MESSAGE         inner join EMAIL using (BIZ_ID)
WHERE MESSAGE_STATUS = 'U' group by FROM_ADD) t on t.FROM_ADD= e.FROM_ADD
WHERE 
 e.FROM_ADD=:FROM_ADD
ORDER BY MAX(e.UPDATED_DATE) DESC, ufrom.USER_FIRST_NAME DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Edited: - Added If count=null to be 0, and added left join to ensure results show up.

edit 2: Changed the subquery to only count unread sent to this user.

Edit 3: Updated 1st query and Added 2nd query depending on required results. This should do the trick.  You probably want the first one.

Comment: This query fails to return data if MESSAGE_STATUS is other that 'U' means if the mail is read....

Comment: Sorry what I meant to say is if 3 messages are sent by user 2, then the query returns finds unread message as 3 for user 2 as well.

Comment: What field links the Email_message table to the Email table - the biz_id?

Comment: Did you try it after my 2nd edit?  It's hard to test exactly on my end without more data in my tables.

Comment: The edited query also considers (in the count) the messages the user sent.

Comment: INSERT INTO USER_CONFIG (USER_ID, USER_FIRST_NAME, USER_LAST_NAME) VALUES ('10002', 'Joe', 'Doe');
INSERT INTO USER_CONFIG (USER_ID, USER_FIRST_NAME, USER_LAST_NAME) VALUES ('10003', 'Marting', 'Wells');
INSERT INTO USER_CONFIG (USER_ID, USER_FIRST_NAME, USER_LAST_NAME) VALUES ('10004', 'Anne', 'Summers');
INSERT INTO USER_CONFIG (USER_ID, USER_FIRST_NAME, USER_LAST_NAME) VALUES ('10005', 'Wayne', 'Bann');
INSERT INTO USER_CONFIG (USER_ID, USER_FIRST_NAME, USER_LAST_NAME) VALUES ('10006', 'Tina', 'Holz');

Comment: INSERT INTO EMAIL (MAIL_NO, BIZ_ID, FROM_ADD, TO_ADD, EMAIL_SUBJECT, MAIL_STATUS, UPDATED_DATE) VALUES ('1', '3-10003-10003', '10003', '10004', 'First Mail', 'A', '2015-06-14 17:58:33');
INSERT INTO EMAIL (MAIL_NO, BIZ_ID, FROM_ADD, TO_ADD, EMAIL_SUBJECT, MAIL_STATUS, UPDATED_DATE) VALUES ('1', '4-10003-10003', '10003', '10005', 'Second Mail', 'A', '2015-06-14 17:44:16');
INSERT INTO EMAIL (MAIL_NO, BIZ_ID, FROM_ADD, TO_ADD, EMAIL_SUBJECT, MAIL_STATUS, UPDATED_DATE) VALUES (‘1’,'5-10003-10001', '10003', '10006', 'Third Mail', 'A', '2015-06-14 17:44:07’);

Comment: INSERT INTO EMAIL_MESSAGE (MESSAGE_NO, BIZ_ID, SENDER, MESSAGE, MESSAGE_STATUS, SEND_LOCATION, READ_DATE, SEND_DATE) VALUES ('1', '3-10003-10003', '10003', 'FEERR', 'R', 'TBD', '2015-06-14 17:59:15', '2015-06-14 17:58:33');
INSERT INTO EMAIL_MESSAGE (MESSAGE_NO, BIZ_ID, SENDER, MESSAGE, MESSAGE_STATUS, SEND_LOCATION, READ_DATE, SEND_DATE) VALUES ('1', '4-10003-10003', '10003', 'Paddd', 'U', 'TBD', NULL, '2015-06-14 17:44:16');

Comment: INSERT INTO EMAIL_MESSAGE (MESSAGE_NO, BIZ_ID, SENDER, MESSAGE, MESSAGE_STATUS, SEND_LOCATION, READ_DATE, SEND_DATE) VALUES ('1', '5-10003-10001', '10003', 'tigerrrr', 'U', 'TBD', NULL, '2015-06-14 17:44:07’);
INSERT INTO EMAIL_MESSAGE (MESSAGE_NO, BIZ_ID, SENDER, MESSAGE, MESSAGE_STATUS, SEND_LOCATION, READ_DATE ,SEND_DATE) VALUES ('2', '3-10003-10003', '10004', 'I am good thanks', 'U', 'TBD', NULL,'2015-06-14 18:24:03');

Comment: data added if that helps

Comment: The data has helped.  But for clairification. You want to retrieve the lasted message received, along with a count of unread messages?  Because your original query uses the FROM_ADD in the where clause which will get the last email sent by the selected user.

Comment: Thats true, I corrected it. The left join now looks like (SELECT COUNT(*) AS UNREAD_MESSAGE_COUNT,TO_ADD, SENDER FROM EMAIL_MESSAGE INNER JOIN EMAIL USING (BIZ_ID)
       WHERE MESSAGE_STATUS = 'U' AND SENDER NOT IN (:SENDER) GROUP BY TO_ADD) em
      ON em.TO_ADD = e.TO_ADD

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80707/discussion-between-user4826347-and-gregory-hart).

Comment: Gregory Hart:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32747353/mysql-left-join-giving-null-values  on not showing unread messages in one of the two scenarios

Comment: There was an issue with the solution, probably I did not make it clear for Gregory to pick that up - Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32747353/mysql-left-join-giving-null-values